# how to deploy and interact with multiple contracts like etherjs

Tags: solana-cli, solang

I want to deploy solidity contracts which have multiple inheritance ,is there any way to deploy that ?
[image]

Comment: Give us a specific use case so there's something that the community can sink their teeth into. You may discover that there's a different solution to your problem other than the one you imagine.